# How to generate url with params in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4

The situation is quite tricky... For example I have URL 
`http://example.com/users`

which shows all users. I also have few filters like

`http://example.com/users?sort_type=ASC&sort_value=surname`

or

`http://example.com/users?sort_type=DESC&sort_value=name`.

There also is the search which looks like this

`http://example.com/users/search/by_name/?search_value=bob`

or `http://example.com/users/search/by_surname/?search_value=miller`.

For the search I also need to add filtering params, so the main problem is in first symbol: when there is the list of users it should be `?`, when search `&`. So is there some url generation function for generating url from URL params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values not using by route mask will append as query params. (change route name from 'users' to yours)

```
URL::route('users', array(
  'sort_type' => 'ASC',
  'sort_value' => 'surname'
));
```

If you don't use routes then use something like this

```
$query = http_build_query(array(
      'sort_type' => 'ASC',
      'sort_value' => 'surname'
));
URL::to(action('UserController@index') . '?' . $query );
```

Comment: Note the route has to be *named* 'users'